# Multiple .js calls from a local host

Tags: javascript, html

I working on an HTML file in which I need to call several .js files from my computer. Below is my directory structure.

```
Dropbox/
├── js/
|   └── .js files
└── abm.html
```

I have the following lines in my html file to verify the path and call the .js files:

```
for(var i = 0; i < paths.length;i++){
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';

  //few lines here 

}else if(location.valueOf().pathname === "/C:/Users/.../Dropbox/abm.html"){
        script.src = "../Dropbox/js" + paths[i];

  //few lines here 
}
```

to call each of the .js files one by one with path[i] containing the .js file names. 
With my browser, I open the HTML file and can see that it can call .js files. However, when pushing a command run bottom nothing happens. Which should actually run the defined model. Can anyone help with this?

Comment: Your script is really bad formatted. You added an `else` to a `for` loop. Kinda weird... what you expect it to do actually? If you open your browser console, you will see something like this: https://i.imgur.com/mKxxkkA.png looking for errors and understanding them is really important as a developer. I don't know if you are an actual developer, but will save you a lot of time, which is good :-)

Comment: Sorry I am new to this. For loop is multiple call and if is for opening the html file it from different places. If I only want to open the html file from my computer and run it is there a better way to call Multiple .js in an html file? And how to include the path of the host computer? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your code has syntax errors. It just won't run but it looks like you have an array of paths pointing to you js scripts that you'd like to load into you html page.

The problem is that the existence of a file in the computer can not be checked from browser's JS engine; there'd be some serious security issues there.

Your best chance is to add those script nodes that you are generating into the dom, open the inspector and see what happens

Also, you should not test your websites by opening the html files from your computer directly in the browser. You should use a http server; check this out: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-server-for-chrome/ofhbbkphhbklhfoeikjpcbhemlocgigb .

Comment: Tnx! Security is not  concerned here. I am just trying to run a code from here: [link] (https://github.com/idshklein/system-optimal-ATIS). I am have no javascript nor html knowledge.  I know that I need to set new path in the html file to be able to run it from my computer. But I have been trying solutions but not succeeded. Any help appreciated here...